# jQuery convert a function to a plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to make this small plugin work but I am stuck at the moment. This is my first attempt to convert a function to a plugin..
Currently it's not working..

```
jQuery.fn.overlay_AS = function(opts) {

            clickable_link.click(function(evt){
                evt.preventDefault();

                var overlay_content = $('#'+current_link);

                overlay.children().fadeOut(200).promise().done(function () {
                    overlay_content.fadeIn();
                });
                //don't need to make the overlay fadeIn every time
                if (!overlay.is(':visible')) overlay.fadeIn(); 
            });

            overlay.click(function(){
                overlay.fadeOut();
                overlay.children().fadeOut(500);
            });         

        };

        $('.p_wrapper p').click(function(){
            $('.p_wrapper p').overlay_AS({
                clickable_link:$(this), 
                current_link:$(this).attr('class'),
                overlay: $('#overlay')
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="p_wrapper">

    <p class="one">Link 1</p>

    <p class="two">Link 2</p>

    <p class="three">Link 3</p>

</div>

<div id="overlay">

    <p id="one">You clicked on p1</p>

    <p id="two">You clicked on p2</p>

    <p id="three">You clicked on p3</p>

</div>
```

ALl it does is fading an overlay in and loading different content depending on what link you clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were still trying to treat the plugin as a normal function instead of a  function that acts on the selected elements.

Changing the plugin code to this does what (I think) you want and only requires you to pass in the overlay that you wish to use as you have already selected the container for the links:

```
jQuery.fn.overlay_AS = function(overlay) {   
    // hide overlay and bind event to fadeout overlays when clicked
    overlay.children().hide();
    overlay.click(function(){
        overlay.children().fadeOut(500);
    }); 

    // return $(this) to enable chaining
    return $(this).each(function() {   // loop so plugin can be applied to multiple elements
        $(this).find('p').click(function(evt){ // bind click to each p tag
            evt.preventDefault();
            var overlayId = $(this).attr('class'); // get the overlay id
            var selectedOverlay = $('#' + overlayId); // select the overlay to show

            // hide overlays then show selected overlay
            overlay.children().fadeOut(500).promise().done(function () {
                selectedOverlay.fadeIn();
            });
        });
    });            
};

$('.p_wrapper').overlay_AS($('#overlay')); // Select the wrapper
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dQePu/)

Another change I would recommend is to use `data` attributes instead of the class to select the overlay:

HTML:

```
 <p data-overlay-id="one">Link 1</p>
```

JS:

```
 var overlayId = $(this).data('overlay-id);
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for your help, I also managed to get it to work slightly different what do you think about this http://jsfiddle.net/c2bAv/2/?

Comment: @Alex That looks alright. Only thing I would change is  `this.click(function(evt){` to `return this.click(function(evt){` so that you can chain other methods after you plugin call if required.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Richard's answer, giving this a read might help as well: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started